# main partition marked as full but / directory only half the size

Tags: partitioning, directory, disk-management

I am new to Linux so please forgive me the question if it's 'easy'.

I recently installed Linux next to Windows 10 on my SSD (I have a separate Partition for this which is 29GB). Then I moved my `/home` directory to my HDD to store files and stuff.

Now, I have the Problem that the OS says that I don't have any space left and in fact when I look at the partition via the disks application or even with the df command it shows it as full but when I take a look at the `/` directory its only 14 somewhat GB large and there is nothing else on this partition which is why I am confused.

If I should add some special information to this question please tell me.

Overview:

```
- main partition on SSD (29GB) (marked as full) has all directories on it except /home (in sum the / directory is only 14GB large)
- secondary partition on HDD (85GB) where I moved my /home to
```

When I run `df -h | grep -v loop` I get this:

```
Datasystem      Size    Used Avab. Used% Mounted on
udev            7,7G       0  7,7G    0% /dev
tmpfs           1,6G     11M  1,6G    1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p6   27G     25G     0  100% /
tmpfs           7,8G    332M  7,4G    5% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M       0  5,0M    0% /run/lock
tmpfs           7,8G       0  7,8G    0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p1  256M     59M  198M   23% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1,6G     20K  1,6G    1% /run/user/131
tmpfs           1,6G    100K  1,6G    1% /run/user/0
/dev/sda1       821G     29G  792G    4% /media/root/DATA
/dev/sda3        95G    9,6G   80G   11% /home
/dev/nvme0n1p3  211G    100G  111G   48% /media/root/Windows
```

Thanks...

Comment: "Then I moved my /home directory to my HDD to store files and stuff." Could you explain a little more? how many partitions for linux do you have? One for the system and one for /home?

Comment: @guillermochamorro okay I added a little overview if this helps understanding the situation a bit more

Comment: Please add output of `df -h | grep -v loop` to your question.

Comment: @mook765 okay I added the output of the command to the question

Comment: Take a look at your `/home` folder from a live session (boot your installer, try without installing) and mount the `/`-partition (`/dev/nvme0n1p6`), browse to the home-folder of this partition and check it's contents. I wouldn't be surprised if you find about 9 GB here.

Comment: I did so and what I have found is a /home folder which is 13GB but I didn‘t see that in the installed version of linux... Is it maybe possible that this is a copy of the moved directory since there aren‘t many files in my /home anyways?

Comment: Is this the procedure you followed to move /home? You may have missed the steps at the end to delete the info in the /home folder once you confirm all data has correctly copied to new  /home partition. To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Comment: @oldfred yes, I think this was the procedure I followed (although I cannot tell for sure) but it seems like I have found the solution for the Problem. I must have somehow forgotten to mount the new /home partition to my drive again after the process so all data got written to a (still existing? or) new created /home on my SSD but the /home reference was linked to the one on my HDD so I did not find it on my SSD. I cannot tell for sure that this is all correct but after deleting my 'ghost' /home and mounting the HDD again it now seems to work just fine so thank you for your support!

Comment: @oldfred I've noticed your allergy to posting answers and accumulating points but in this case it would be nice to have an answer posted. Ping me please if you post one.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I posted an answer, but it really is just a link to a standard help.ubuntu set of instructions.

Comment: @oldfred Thanks and upvoted. Many answers are summaries of links. It's important for questions to be answered so they don't keep popping up year after year unanswered long after the OP last visited the site.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix While generally agreeing with you, the fact is the same questions keep popping up regardless.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I meant the EXACT SAME question will keep popping up year after year until answered. No doubt similar questions will pop up but they would get closed as duplicates of this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good link on how to move /home from a folder inside / (root) to a new partition. To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Once you have copied /home to new partition, and confirmed that copy is correct you can then delete the info in /home folder inside / (root).

Of course good backups before any major changes are needed just in case.